# Django sorl-thumbnail does not display images

Tags: django

I try to use Django sorl-thumbnail but it does not display images (and does't show any errors).

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'sorl.thumbnail',
)
```

Models:

```
class Toy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Name')
    image = ImageField(upload_to='site_media/images')
```

templates:

```
<div id="toy">
                {% for p in toys %}
                    <div class="toy">
                                # toy.image - this is model_name.image field
                            {% thumbnail toy.image "100x700" as im %}
                            <img style="margin:{{ im|margin:"100x700" }}" src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.x }}" height="{{ im.y }}">
                            {% endthumbnail %}

                            <p>
                            <span> {{ p.name }} </span>
                            <span> {{p.unit_price}} </span>
                            </p>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^site_media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root' : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')}),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Have you imported](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#model-examples) ImageField from sorl in model definition? It's necessary to get it working automatically.

Moreover [you need to run in console](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#setup) `./manage.py syncdb` because in default configuration sorl keeps cached names of thumbnails in database. It has to create its own table in database for that.

Could you also show your settings of STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS, etc?

Answer (score 15):

Actually, using the ImageField from sorl is only necessary to [automatically delete](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#model-examples) thumbnails when the original image is deleted.

sorl.thumbnail by default does not display any errors and fails silently if thumbnail creation was not successful. To see the errors, add

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
```

to your settings.py. This should help you fix the problem.

Comment: Added the above settings to the settings file, still no errors and no images rendered. :/

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. This showed us, that the command `gm` was missing. It would be great, if this setting would default to the value of `settings.DEBUG`.